# Dynamic width div auto resize to fit browser width?

Tags: html, css, autoresize, flexbox

I have several div with unknown width(dynamic width).
How can I auto resize these div to fit browser width?

For example, I have 5 div with difference width. If the browser width only able to fill up 3 div then those 3 div will auto resize to fit the browser width and the rest will display at second row.

How can I make it using html5 and css3. I know that a new feature flexbox in css3 but i am not sure whether I can deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can play with the calss - value acording your request.
min/max width/height

see example [demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/aYx7h/2/)

```
    .grid {
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.column {
  padding: 20px;
}
.fluid {
  box-flex: 1;
  background: #ccc;
}
.fixed {
    width: 100px;
  background: red;
}​
```